# Is there any possible way, to rewrite code with mapping an array and using "useEffect" from functional component to class component?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, mapping

I use my Logs component to map logs from an array of objects. My problem is, that using "useEffect" it makes my application very slow. Is there any possible way to rewrite it to class component?

my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Log from "../logs/log";
import "../../scss/logs.scss";
const Logs = ({ logs, changeDetailState, getLogId, onClick, mountLogs }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    mountLogs();
  });
  const logsmap = logs.map((log, i) => (
    <Log
      onClick={onClick}
      getLogId={getLogId}
      changeDetailState={changeDetailState}
      key={i}
      input={log.amount}
      description={log.description}
      id={i}
    />
  ));
  return <div className="logs">{logsmap}</div>;
};
export default Logs;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform it to a `Class Component` by doing the follow:

```
class Logs extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { mountLogs } = this.props;

        mountLogs();
    }
}

processLogsMap = () => {
    const { logs } = this.props;
    logs.map((log, i) => (
    <Log
      onClick={onClick}
      getLogId={getLogId}
      changeDetailState={changeDetailState}
      key={i}
      input={log.amount}
      description={log.description}
      id={i}
    />
  ));
}

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="logs">{processLogsMap()}</div>; 
        </>
    )
}

export default Logs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking mountLogs(), every time a property is changing.

If you want it to run just once upon mount, then use:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    mountLogs();
  }, []);
```

If you want to run on specific values changes then you should use:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    mountLogs();
  }, [logs, changeDetailState]);
```

For Running it once, it should be used as below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Log from "../logs/log";
import "../../scss/logs.scss";
const Logs = ({ logs, changeDetailState, getLogId, onClick, mountLogs }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    mountLogs();
  }, []);
  const logsmap = logs.map((log, i) => (
    <Log
      onClick={onClick}
      getLogId={getLogId}
      changeDetailState={changeDetailState}
      key={i}
      input={log.amount}
      description={log.description}
      id={i}
    />
  ));
  return <div className="logs">{logsmap}</div>;
};
export default Logs;
```